# Wordpress - How to avoid adsense ads when viewing thru android App

Tags: android, wordpress, webview, adsense

I have a WordPress website, it is responsive and use AdSense advt. in it. I am creating an android app (Webview) for the same, however in android webview I want to hide AdSense ad.

Is there any way to block the adsense on android webview.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the behavior of AdSense ads on different devices, browsers and resolution, and various other customization controls through  [Advance-Ads](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-ads/) plugin.